# How to take take SQL output from server console and run it in server's rails console, in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I want to be able to reproduce in the rails console an error like this from the rails server log:

```
D, [2015-06-30T13:41:57.442121 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.0ms)  BEGIN
D, [2015-06-30T13:41:57.444003 #3] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "tracking_browsers" ("campaign_id", "channel_id", "browser_id", "hits") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["campaign_id", 6], ["channel_id", 3], ["browser_id", 4], ["hits", 1]]
D, [2015-06-30T13:41:57.446468 #3] DEBUG -- :    (2.0ms)  COMMIT
D, [2015-06-30T13:41:57.449973 #3] DEBUG -- :   Unit Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "units".* FROM "units" WHERE "units"."campaign_id" = $1 AND "units"."unit_media_id" = $2  [["campaign_id", 6], ["unit_media_id", 2]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass
```

Ideally I want to just be able to copy paste this line:

```
SELECT "units".* FROM "units" WHERE "units"."campaign_id" = $1 AND "units"."unit_media_id" = $2  [["campaign_id", 6], ["unit_media_id", 2]]
```

Into an SQL method like `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`, but that doesn't quite seem to work, because of the brackets.

I know I can replace $1 and $2 with the values 6 and 2, and delete the last brackets, like this, but it is cumbersome:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT "units".* FROM "units" WHERE "units"."campaign_id" = 6 AND "units"."unit_media_id" = 2')
```

Is there any method that will let me just copy past without having to manually modify the $ parameters and delete the brackets?

Comment: Why don't you try to reproduce in development environment. https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger can help you find the issue.

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace? It looks like the problem may not be in your SQL query, but instead your Ruby code.

Comment: The NoMethodError is in my ruby code, yes, but that's not what I'm interested in. I've already fixed that.